# How to convert my List<Object> from JSON to Java and use every element of it

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm building simple rest REST. And I can't get elements from my Entity Table as Java objects. I'm trying to get every price and SUM all prices.

```
   @Entity
   @Table (name="purchase")
   public class Purchase {

 @Column(name="price")
 private BigDecimal price;
 }
   @Service
   public List<Purchase> getAllPurchase() {
    List<Purchase> purchase = new ArrayList<>();
    purchaseRepository.findAll().forEach(purchase::add);
    return purchase;
}
 Controller
 @RequestMapping("/purchase")
    public List<Purchase> getAllTopics(){
        return purchaseService.getAllPurchase();            
    }
```

All I need is to get every price of my purchase and SUM it. But I just get `JSON` and don't know what to do next. Is there any annotation for this job? All I found was `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()` but `get.price()` always returns `null` for me.

Comment: You don't need to convert anything from JSON. You get your List<Purchase>, and loop through it to sum all the prices. An annotation won't do that for you. You need to write the code for it.

Comment: But how can I loop through when i don't have Java object. How is it possible for me to getPrice() from my Purchase, it always will return null.

Comment: If it always returns null, it means that all your purchases have a null price. Fix the data in your database if they aren't supposed to have a null price, set a not null constraint if that's never supposed to happen, and fix your loop in order to ignore null prices if it is supposed to happen.

Comment: @YurlyShkinder Can you please fix your code formatting? With your use of brackets and indentation it's not very clear what belongs where.

Comment: and I still didn't get the rigth way to do my job done. What is the way to get all elements from my list of JSON?